# How did all the Doctors know to save Gallifrey?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

In *The Day of the Doctor*, all the Doctors came to save Gallifrey (no sir, all thirteen!). My question is: how did all the Doctors know to come? Only the three Doctors (10, 11, 8.5) were brought together by the moment, after all. So how did they know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

12th Doctor (Capaldi) knew to come because 11 (Smith) retained his own memories.

For the others it's not shown on-screen, but we can safely assume that War (Hurt), 10 (Tennant), and 11 contacted the rest of their incarnations and convinced them to come and help.  Supposedly their memories of this event would also be erased just like War's and 10's, as to not pollute the timeline.

Comment: This does of course mean that the doctor’s *next* incarnation is going to be missing, as will any thereafter.

Comment: @KRyan Well, if 13 Doctors was enough to save Gallifrey, then a 14th Doctor isn't needed.

Comment: how did 11 (Smith) retained 12th Doctor (Capaldi)  memories. so he knew to come save Gallifrey?

Comment: This isn't worded quite right. 11 retained his *own* memories, so 12 knew to come because he already saw himself there.  Wibbley-wobbley.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: In fact, they only had to contact the First Doctor, who would begin the calculations and leave a message for his successors. Presumably, the calculations weren't finished until the Twelfth Doctor's time.